# What type of stand is needed for a beauty dish?

Tags: lighting, off-camera-flash, support-equipment, beauty-dish, lightstands

I've never used a beauty dish and I'm not sure what's the typical way of positioning it. I want to shoot on location and not in a studio setup, and I don't have an assistant.

What kind of stand do I need in this case? a regular one or a C-stand with the arms?

Comment: What type of lighting will you be using on location flashguns or studio strobes?

Comment: @HarryJamesSanderson Sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "what type of lighting"

Comment: @user1899082 He's asking if you're using battery-powered hotshoe flashes, or big plug-into-the-wall-outline studio flashes.

Comment: !@inkista big flashes but cordless, Profoto B1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a little abstract...

- If your flash heads are heavy you need a sturdy stand.
- If you are on the outside you could use a sandbag to add weight.
- If you are using the light just a fill light or lateral, or whatever light you can use any stand.
- If you are taking **specificly butterfly lighting** then a boom tripod or C-stand it is usefull, but not indispensable.
- And if you are using it as a **cenital hairlight**, in this case probably a C-stand is the only way to go.